# Multiple layer added in tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch, swift3

[image]

I am trying to set data on tableview dynamically and cell can be deleted by swiping.cell create multiple layer and after deletion some layer is exist,its appear cell has not deleted.

my code is here ..

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.beaconArrayM = NSMutableArray()
        self.produsctListM = NSMutableArray()
        self.contentArrayM = NSMutableArray()


        self.fatchDataFromApiAsync(urlString: videoUrl)//video url
        countBeacons = 0

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    }


    func fatchDataFromApiAsync(urlString:String) {

        _ = NSArray()
        let url:URL = URL(string: urlString)!

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url){ data,response,error in

            if error != nil {
                print("Data Parsing error = \(error)")
            }
            else{
                do{
                    let jsonResponse      =   try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! [String:AnyObject]
                    if jsonResponse["assets"] != nil{
                        self.jsonArray = jsonResponse["assets"] as! NSArray
                        self.HeaderStr = jsonResponse["identifier"] as? String
                        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = self.HeaderStr

                        self.beaconManager.delegate = self
                        self.swipeTableview.delegate = self
                        self.swipeTableview.dataSource = self
                    }
                }
                catch let error as NSError{
                    print("\(error)")
                }
            }
            }.resume()
    }
}


extension DemoListBeaconsVC: ESTBeaconManagerDelegate
{
    //  :MARK BeaconsManager ranging delegates


    func beaconManager(_ manager: Any, didEnter region: CLBeaconRegion) {

        countBeacons += 1
        if !(region.minor == nil){
            let minorValue = region.minor
            if !(self.beaconArrayM.contains(minorValue!)){
                self.beaconArrayM .add(minorValue!)
            }
            self.contentArrayM = self.beaconArrayM
            self.swipeTableview.reloadData()
        }

    }

    func downloadImage(url: URL,indexPath: IndexPath,productTxt : String) {
        let cell = self.swipeTableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! SwipeTableViewCell

        print("Download Started")
        getDataFromUrl(url: url) { (data, response, error)  in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }
            print(response?.suggestedFilename ?? url.lastPathComponent)
            print("Download Finished")
            DispatchQueue.main.async() { () -> Void in
                    cell.productImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
                    cell.productImage.image = UIImage(data: data)
                    cell.contentLbl.text = productTxt

            }
        }
    }

    func getDataFromUrl(url: URL, completion: @escaping (_ data: Data?, _  response: URLResponse?, _ error: Error?) -> Void) {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {
            (data, response, error) in
            completion(data, response, error)
            }.resume()
    }

    func beaconManager(_ manager: Any, didExitRegion region: CLBeaconRegion) {

        countBeacons -= 1
//      if countBeacons == 0{
//      }
        if (((self.beaconArrayM.count)) > 0 && !(region.minor == nil)){
            self.beaconArrayM.remove(region.minor!)
            self.contentArrayM = self.beaconArrayM
            self.swipeTableview.reloadData()
        }
    }


    func beaconManager(_ manager: Any, didDetermineState state: CLRegionState, for region: CLBeaconRegion) {
        switch state {
        case CLRegionState.inside:
            if region == beaconRegion
            {
                self.beaconManager.startMonitoring(for: beaconRegion)
            }
            else if region == beaconRegion
            {
                self.beaconManager.startMonitoring(for: beaconRegion2)
            }
            else if region == beaconRegion
            {
                self.beaconManager.startMonitoring(for: beaconRegion3)
            }

            print("inside REGION",region.description)
            break
        case CLRegionState.outside:
            // Stop Monitoring
            if region == beaconRegion
            {
                self.beaconManager.stopMonitoring(for: beaconRegion)
            }
            else if region == beaconRegion
            {
                self.beaconManager.stopMonitoring(for: beaconRegion2)
            }
            else if region == beaconRegion
            {
                self.beaconManager.stopMonitoring(for: beaconRegion3)
            }
            print("outside REGION",region.description)

            break
        case CLRegionState.unknown:
            print("unknown REGION",region.description)
            break
        }
    }

    func beaconManager(_ manager: Any, didChange status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {

        switch status {
        case .authorizedAlways:
            self.beaconManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            print("authorizedAlways")
            break
        default:
            print("defaultt")
            break
        }
    }

    func beaconManager(_ manager: Any, rangingBeaconsDidFailFor region: CLBeaconRegion?, withError error: Error) {

    }

    func beaconManager(_ manager: Any, didFailWithError error: Error) {

    }

    func beaconManager(_ manager: Any, didStartMonitoringFor region: CLBeaconRegion) {
        if region == beaconRegion
        {
            self.beaconManager.requestState(for: beaconRegion)
        }
        else if region == beaconRegion
        {
            self.beaconManager.requestState(for: beaconRegion2)
        }
        else if region == beaconRegion
        {
            self.beaconManager.requestState(for: beaconRegion3)
        }
    }

    func beaconManager(_ manager: Any, monitoringDidFailFor region: CLBeaconRegion?, withError error: Error) {

    }


}


//: MARK Tableview delegate and datasource

extension DemoListBeaconsVC : UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate
{

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let identifier = "Cell"
        //      print("Begin cellForRowAt")
        let cell = self.swipeTableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as! SwipeTableViewCell

        if (self.contentArrayM.count) > 0 {
            var currentIndex: Int = 0
            let countIndex: Int = 0
            for tempp in self.contentArrayM{
                    let temp = jsonArray .object(at: indexPath.row)
                    self.jsonDic = temp as! NSDictionary
                    self.minor = self.jsonDic["minor"] as? String
                    if let minorInteger = Int(self.minor!) {
                    minorNumber = NSNumber(value:minorInteger)
                    }
                    if minorNumber == tempp as! NSNumber
                    {
                        currentIndex = countIndex
                        break
                    }
                }
//      let temp = jsonArray .object(at: currentIndex)
                let temp = jsonArray .object(at: indexPath.row)
                self.jsonDic = temp as! NSDictionary
                self.minor = self.jsonDic["minor"] as? String
                self.HeaderStr = self.jsonDic["title"] as? String
                self.urlStr = self.jsonDic["url"] as? String
                print("minor",self.minor!)

                if let minorInteger = Int(self.minor!) {
                    minorNumber = NSNumber(value:minorInteger)
                }
            }
            let url = NSURL(string: self.urlStr!)
            downloadImage(url: url as! URL, indexPath: indexPath, productTxt: self.HeaderStr!)
        return cell
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
    {
        return 100.0
    }


    func actionGesture(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
    {

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        let temp = jsonArray .object(at: indexPath.row)
        self.jsonDic = temp as! NSDictionary
        self.HeaderStr = self.jsonDic["title"] as? String
        self.urlStr = self.jsonDic["url"] as? String

        let demoVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProductDetalsVC") as! ProductDetalsVC
        demoVC.productTitle = self.HeaderStr
        demoVC.imageStr = self.urlStr
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(demoVC, animated: true)
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

        let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Delete")
        { action, index in
            //          print("delete")
            self.swipeTableview.beginUpdates()
            self.contentArrayM.removeObject(at: indexPath.row)
            self.swipeTableview.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
            print("array count after deletion",self.contentArrayM.count)
//                      self.swipeTableview.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.fade)
            self.swipeTableview.endUpdates()
        }
        let done = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "Done")
        { action, index in
            print("done")
        }
        return [delete, done]
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        // the cells you would like the actions to appear needs to be editable
        return true
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

  if editingStyle == .delete {
        print("Deleted")

        self.contentArrayM.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        self.swipeTableview.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
  }
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if self.contentArrayM.count == 0
        {
            return 0
        }
        else
        {
            return self.contentArrayM.count
        }

    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
    {
        return 1
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer finally.
I was created tableview cell two time ,  First in cellForRowAtIndexPath and Second in function downloadImage().

Now i am sending cell into function downloadImage() as follow.

> downloadImage(cell: cell, url: url!, indexPath: indexPath, productTxt: self.headerStr!)